# How to disagree to iTunes privacy policy?

Tags: macos, itunes

I accidentally pressed that I agree to iTunes tos when I opened the app on Mac os Sierra. The fact is I don't agree to the tos. How can I get the dialog option back? I don't plan to use iTunes.

Comment: If you don't plan to use iTunes, delete it from your machine.

Comment: I tried deleting it but I got a pop-up telling me that it can't be deleted

Comment: @Wideem, I updated my answer with directions to delete iTunes.app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you open iTunes for the first time and agree to the license agreement, it creates the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist` file with a dictionary entry called `license-agreements`. You can just delete the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist` file if you have no intension of using iTunes and it will be as if you never agreed to the license agreement.

In Terminal:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist
```

If you just want to delete the `license-agreements` use:

```
defaults delete com.apple.itunes license-agreements
```

---

If you want to remove the iTunes app in macOS, you should be able to just move it to the Trash and then empty the Trash. I was able to do that in macOS 10.12.3, however you might have to disable System Integrity Protection and if so, do the following:

- Shutdown your Mac.
- Start up from macOS Recovery using: <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>
- Select your Language and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- At macOS Utilities, select Terminal from the Utilities menu.
- In Terminal type, `csrutil disable` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In Terminal type, `reboot` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Once back in normal mode macOS, in Terminal use the following command:

  ```
  sudo rm -fr /Applications/iTunes.app
  ```
- Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type your password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

Don't forget to enable System Integrity Protection afterwards. Repeat the necessary steps, however use `csrutil enable`.

Answer (score -1):

It is likely that the only way to un-ring that bell would be to back up your files and create a new account on your Mac, migrate those files, and delete the old profile. You could then launch iTunes and disagree but I believe all that does is just quit the app, so if you launch it again it will ask, again, if you agree.

And iTunes like most of the apps that come with macOS can't be deleted.